# Compile time error - member cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, class, instance

I'm a new trying to understand classes and how classes work. I'm building a small console program and am currently working on my 'class.cs' file which I titled 'LineItem.cs' as it will handle the line items on the receipt that I am trying to have my console application generate.

> PROBLEM: Member 'A070_**Classes**_CashRegister.Program.receipt()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. (Error Line: #21/Column #13)

I thought that i had done this on line #21 when I entered 'this.color = price;

Code:

```
using System;
namespace a070___Classes___CashRegister
{
  class LineItem     // Class name is singular
                     // receipt might be better name for this class?
  {
    /// Class Attributes
    private String product;     // constructor attribute
    private String description;
    private String color;
    private double price;
    private Boolean isAvailable;

    // constructor called to make object => LineItem
    public LineItem(String product, String description, String color, int price, Boolean isAvailable)
    {
        this.product = product;
        this.description = description;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;// might want to do an availability check
    }

    //Getters
    public String GetProduct() {return product;}
    public String GetDescription(){return description;}//Send description
    public String GetColor() {return color;}

    //Setter
    public void SetColor(string color)//we might want to see it in other colors if is option
    { this.color = color; } //changes object color 
  }
}
```

Main file which will call the class:

```
using System;

namespace a070___Classes___CashRegister
{
  class Program
  {
    static void receipt()
    { 
    //stuff goes here - we call various instances of the class to generate some receipts
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Program CashRegister = new Program();
        //CashRegister.receipt();

        //Program CashRegister = new Program();
        //CashRegister.receipt();

        receipt();// Don't need to instantiate Program, console applications framework will find the static function Main
        //unless changed your project properties.
        //Since reciept is member od Program and static too, you can just call it directly, without qualification.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code does not show `reciept`, neither use or declaration.

Comment: Please make sure to read error explanation on MSDN: [CS0176](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcxt2bd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Side note: please avoid long "new here"/"searched alot"/"thankyou notes" text in the post. Instead consider adding sample code that relates to your error.

Comment: I read MSDN: CS0176, but did not understand it or how it relates to my issue unfortunately. I posted the code up which is the other file that will call the class. I'm trying to build my class file first, my errors all happen in my class file (which is one error total).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Program CashRegister = new Program();
CashRegister.receipt();
```

should be

```
Program.receipt();
```

or just

```
receipt();
```

You don't need  to instantiate `Program`, with console applications the framework will find the `static function Main(...` and call that by magic, unless you've changed your project properties.

Since `receipt` is a member of `Program` and `static` too, you can just call it directly, without qualification.

---

The `receipt()` function is `static` but you are trying the call it from an instance.

You are not showing either where `receipt` is declared or where you are calling it from so I can't help more.

Perhaps you have a line of code, somewhere in it there is an expression like,

```
... this.receipt() ...
```

or

```
... yourInstance.receipt() ...
```

but should be,

```
... Type.receipt() ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the general explanation, that is appreciated. I'm assuming that when you say 'receipt()', you are referring to the 'Class LineItem' yes? How would i fix this? i've tried changing 'int price' on line #16 to 'double price' and 'Double price' but those only added errors. none of the other 'this' elements produce an error. I am very confused. Again, thank you for the help

Comment: @Chezshire, I'm referring to the `reciept()` that is explicity cited in your exception message. Hence, I can know, this is not the right code.

Comment: I revised my main file to reflect the 'reciept()' statement as you suggested and that cleared up everything. I am now googling a bit of stuff on the things folks have mentioned in this thread to work on increasing my understanding. Thank you for your help. I also updated my main code file.

Comment: @Jodrell - In your answer you spell "receipt" in 2 different ways. You should spell them all the same, preferably the correct way: "recEIpt", not "recIEpt".

Comment: @DavideAndrea, fixed, I think

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a static method with an instance.

All you need to do is to access it with the class like this:

```
LineItem.receipt();
```

Note: You haven't mention the other code so I don't know where the method receipt locates so I have assumed that it is in the LineItem class.

And one more thing, it is better to call methods with a capital letter - Receipt.

Comment: Thank you Misha, your comments were very helpful and appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the (R)eceipt Misha. Every bit helps and every bit is appreciated.